# Definability of Forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am studying Kunen's Set Theory and in the section where the atomic definability lemma is discussed, it just says the notion $p\Vdash^* \phi$, where $\phi$ is atomic, is obviously definable over $M$. The problem is that it doesn't mention an explicit $\{\in \}$- formula that defines the atomic formula. Can anyone help me understand it or actually give a proof of it?

Comment: What do you mean by “defines the atomic formula”?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I mean the ${\in}$ formula that defines the set in Kunen's definability lemma, in the case where $\phi$ is atomic i.e. either of the form $a=b$ or $a\in b$.

Comment: Don’t have the book in front of me, but he gives definitions of $p\vDash\sigma\in\tau$ and $p\vDash\sigma=\tau$ via recursion on name-rank of $\sigma$ and $\tau$, right? Why wouldn’t those be (painstakingly) expressible as $\in$-formulas? (Note these formulas would take $\sigma$, $\tau$, $p$, as well as the forcing poset $P$ as input variables.)

Comment: Would they be expressible? If yes, can I have a proof that they would?

Comment: I’m asking you why wouldn’t they be? Why would you ask this question about these definitions as opposed to any other definition in Kunen’s book?

Comment: It is a definition by transfinite recursion. See Kunen's section on transfinite recursion for details.